# Geometry Problem Concerning Trisection Points on a Convex Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral, and let $P$, $Q$, $R$, $S$, $T$, $U$, $V$, and $W$ be the trisection points of the sides of $ABCD$, as shown.

[image]

If the area of quadrilateral $ABCD$ is 180, then find the area of hexagon $AQRCUV$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Since $BQ = AB/3$, $BR = BC/3$, and $\angle QBR = \angle ABC$, triangles $QBR$ and $ABC$ are SAS-similar. Furthermore, since $Q$ and $R$ are trisection points, the side lengths are in a $3:1$ ratio so the areas are in a $9:1$ ratio. This gives
$[BQR] = \frac{[ABC]}{9}.$

[image]

Likewise, triangles $ACD$ and $VUD$ are similar, and
$[VUD] = \frac{[ACD]}{9}.$
Therefore,
$[BQR] + [VUD] = \frac{[ABC] + [ACD]}{9} = \frac{[ABCD]}{9} = \frac{180}{9} = 20.$
The remainder of quadrilateral $ABCD$ is hexagon $AQRCUV$, so it has area $180 - 20 = \boxed{160}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration of @dxiv 's answer.

It is sufficient to just consider just the upper half.

[image]

It should be clear that QR // AC. Then, $\triangle BQR \sim \triangle BAC$

[**Fact:-** When 2 objects are similar, the ratio of their areas is equal to the square of the ratio of their corresponding sides. That is, $\dfrac {A'}{A} = (\dfrac {L'}{L})^2$.]

Therefore, $[\triangle BQR] = (\dfrac {BQ}{BA})^2 \times [\triangle BAC] = \dfrac {1}{9} \times [\triangle BAC]$.

**Added:-** Similarly,  $[\triangle DVU] = \dfrac {1}{9} \times [\triangle DAC]$.

Then, [the un-shaded region] = ... = $\dfrac {1}{9} \times [quad. ABCD]$.

Finally, [the shaded region] = $\dfrac {8}{9} \times [quad. ABCD]$.

Comment: That's an interesting approach...

Comment: Maybe you could develop that a bit to completely solve and find the area of the hexagon.

Comment: @SilasButter See added.

Comment: Could that lead to the area?

Comment: If so, could you provide an explanation?

Comment: @SilasButter Is the added fact the explanation you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for, not only an approach to find the area, but also a solution to the problem.

Comment: Just realized that the area was $\frac89\cdot{180}=160$.

Comment: @SilasButter ABCD need not be cyclic. Just plugin 180 in the last equality to get [the shaded region] = $\dfrac {8}{9} \times [quad. ABCD] = \dfrac {8}{9} \times 180 = 160$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;S_{BRQ} = \cfrac{1}{9} S_{BCA}\,$.